# Quando testando meu web API C# ASP.NET localmente no Fiddler ele me retorna um erro 404

Tags: c#, web-service, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-2

Estou criando um sistema de controle de estoque com integração de aplicativo android,a conexão está sendo feita por meio de um Web Service API. Contudo eu não consigo testar os metódos que existem nele para ver os resultados retornados,estou usando o Fiddler mas sempre que chamo a url por ele o mesmo retorna-me o erro 404 not found. A linguagem de programação usada é o C# e estou usando do ASP.NET 4.6.

Muito obrigado desde já. Por favor se alguém tiver pistas ou noção mais profunda aceito ajuda urgente.

Segue abaixo Screenshots do Project Explorer,do Erro do Fiddler assim como alguns Códigos

***Controller:***

```
using System;
using APITeste.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace APITeste.Controllers
{
    public class PessoaController1 : ApiController
    {
        private static List<Models.Pessoa> _pessoas = new List<Models.Pessoa>();
        // GET: api/Pessoa
        public IEnumerable<Models.Pessoa> Get()
        {
            return _pessoas;
        }

        // GET: api/Pessoa/5
        public Models.Pessoa Get(int id)
        {
            return _pessoas.FirstOrDefault(pessoa => pessoa.ID.Equals(id));
        }

        // POST: api/Pessoa
        public void Post([FromBody]Models.Pessoa value)
        {
            _pessoas.Add(value);
        }

        // PUT: api/Pessoa/5
        public void Put(int id, Models.Pessoa value)
        {
            var pessoa = Get(id);
            if (pessoa != null)
            {
                pessoa.Nome = value.Nome;
                pessoa.Sobrenome = value.Sobrenome;
            }
        }

        // DELETE: api/Pessoa/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            var pessoa = Get(id);
            if (pessoa != null)
                _pessoas.Remove(pessoa);
        }
    }
}
```

***Model:***

```
namespace APITeste.Models
{
    public class Pessoa
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Sobrenome { get; set; }
    }
}
```

***Fiddler Debugger:***

[image: Fiddler Debugger Screenshot]

***Solution Explorer:***

[image: Solution Explorer Screenshot]

Comment: Dica: Selecionar o código e clicar **`Ctrl`** + **`K`** deixa ele formatadinho.

Comment: Tente renomear `PessoaController1` para `PessoaController`

Comment: cara.....eu mal acredito,eu só precisei tirar o 1 como vc falou....e o Fiddler conseguiu ler ele. Eu te juro que to a 3 dias quase sem dormir tentando resolver isso,muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o *controller* pessoa está com o nome `PessoaController1`.

Os *controllers* precisam ter apenas ***Controller*** no final do nome.

Renomeie a classe **`PessoaController1`** para **`PessoaController`**.

Obs.: Renomear a classe, o arquivo é indiferente.